# Need to retrieves the private key for public certificates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-certificate-manager

**Requirement** - Any API exist to get private key for public certificate as the public certificate is created by a client

Export certificate does the same, but only for private certificate - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/sdk-export.html

Answer (score 1):

Its **not possible** with ACM public certificate. You have create your own keys and import to ACM, then you have the private key), or simply not use ACM.

Comment: In our case public certificate would be created by the client.

Comment: @Prakash_Thales It does not matter. You can't access private certificates in public ACM. You have to re-architect your application to never require that, or not use ACM.